# Excel: Calculating Employees Working Hours in a Project

Tags: excel, excel-2007

I am preparing an excel file to calculate Total Project hours. As a part of it, I want to calculate the hours each employee worked for.
In Excel 2007 my data looks something like this:

Task Name - Employee Name - Hours Took

Task 1    - Employee 1    - 4

Task 2    - Employee 2    - 12

Task 3    - Employee 1    - 2

Task 4    - Employee 1    - 4

Task 5    - Employee 3    - 2

and so on...

Now, I want to know how much hours each employee work for

Employee 1 - (what code shall I enter here?)

Employee 2 - (what code shall I enter here?)

Employee 3 - (what code shall I enter here?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to use the SUMIF formula. This is assuming your data is in columns A, B, and C:

```
=SUMIF($B$2:$B$6,"Employee 1",$C$2:$C$6)
=SUMIF($B$2:$B$6,"Employee 2",$C$2:$C$6)
=SUMIF($B$2:$B$6,"Employee 3",$C$2:$C$6)
```

Answer (score 0):

1.a. If not in 3 columns yet try to parse/rearrange data to get into Task, Employee, and Time columns

1.b. from there you can summarize different ways to get your answer. Such as:

1. Select the range of data,
2. Create pivot table
3. Rearrange pivot table as you like to find total of time worked by employee. you also can rearrange to get totals for, project, for time period, etc.